# Socket reading and writing from a web browser app

Tags: javascript, c++, browser, tcp, future-proof

There is a server I need to talk to that publishes a protocol over TCP/IP for querying data from a database and listening on a socket to receive notifications when data is updated. The sever guys provide a Java API which uses this TCP protocol. This means I *could* easily write a Swing App to talk to this server.

I would like a browser based solution. As the protocol is known to me, could I do this in JavaScript? My app will have to display the data in a table. I have heard of Web Sockets but I'm not sure if it will allow this two way communication. Is it *feasible*? Is there a better way that is cross platform and will work in most browsers? Should I be considering a Java Swing based solution that runs inside a browser?

EDIT: What about changing the code in my C++ server to add an additional interface that my Javascript code can communicate directly with it?

Answer (score 1):

The WebSocket protocol differs from TCP/IP sockets. You will have to write something to link them together.

You can do this perfectly well in JavaScript: use [Node.js](http://www.nodejs.org). There's enough tutorials to be found on the subject. The best way to link it to your in-browser JS is through [Socket.IO](http://socket.io).

- Create a Node.js server that connects to the api
- Make the server talk to your web app
- Use it :)

This will work cross-platform and cross-browser (Socket.IO can use/emulate websockets even on IE6(!!)). You'll have to run a server-app (the Node.js app) though.

My personal opinion is that if you want a web/browser based solution, you should use native technology, and not Java.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @ame I have added more to my question. The gist is could I change my C++ server to support a web sockets friendly API and get my JavaScript  code to use that?